# Issue with RegionFunction in DensityPlot

Tags: plotting, regions

I don't get why RegionFunction troncates even the places where x+y<1 !

```
{error, xf} = FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, Tan[Pi/3]}/2}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
DP = Show[DensityPlot[x^2*(-1 + x^2/(0.7^2)) + y^2*(-1 + y^2/0.7^2) - y*x, {x, 0, 1}, {y,0, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x + y <= 1]]]
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[First@DP, xf]]
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the tips of the triangle respect the condition but they miss !

Comment: Use `PlotRange -> All` in `DensityPlot`